# New environment in latex using other environments, compiler doesn't find the \end

Tags: latex

I'm setting up a new environment for my latex document for consistent tables. It looks like this:

```
\newenvironment{defaultTable}[2] {
    \begin{table}[h]
    \noindent
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}
    \specialrule{0.5pt}{10pt}{0pt} \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
} {
    \bottomrule 
    \endtabularx
    \caption{#2}
    \end{table}
}
```

It doesn't seem to find the \end{table} though:

! LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 23 ended by \end{document}.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `\begin{table}` with `\@float{table}` and replace `\end{table}` with `\end@float`.

The `\@float` and `\end@float` are LaTeX's internal commands for starting and ending the float environment.

You'll also want to follow Alexey's advice on the #2 parameter.  Store it in the first part of your environment (`\gdef\mycaption{#2}`) and then recall it later `\caption{\mycaption}` in the second part.  Put `\def\mycaption{\relax}` just before the `\begin{defaultTable}` line.

Also, since `\@float` and `\end@float` have `@` signs in them, if this code is in the preamble of your document file (instead of say, a `.sty` file), you'll need to put `\makeatletter` before your `\begin{defaultTable}` and also `\makeatother` after `\end{defaultTable}`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use #2 in the end if you use the xparse mechanism:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{defaultTable}{+m+m}{%
    \begin{table}[h]
    \noindent
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}
    \specialrule{0.5pt}{10pt}{0pt} \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
} {%
    \bottomrule 
    \endtabularx
    \caption{#2}
    \end{table}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `#2` in the last argument of the `\newenvironment` macros. You should use #1..#9 in the second argument only.

Save your `#2` to `\tempa` (or any macros). And use `\tempa` in the caption.

```
\newenvironment{defaultTable}[2]{
  \begin{table}[h]
  \def\tempa{#2}
  \noindent    
  \tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}    \specialrule{0.5pt}{10pt}{0pt} \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
}{    
 \bottomrule     
 \endtabularx    
 \caption{\tempa}
 \end{table}
}
```

Comment: Thx for the hint, it doesn't solve the problem though, I still get the error that \begin{table} is ended by \end{document}

Comment: Write full version of your file with preambule.

Answer (score 1):

I've has the same problem, and it is because of the "\end{tabularx}". The solution is:

> \newenvironment{defaultTable}[3] { 
>       \begin{table}[h]
>       **\caption{#2}**
>       \noindent
>       \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{#1}
>       \specialrule{0.5pt}{10pt}{0pt} \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
>       **#3**
>       \bottomrule 
>       \end{tabularx}
>  } {
>       \end{table} }

So you define the rows as a parameter.

Regards,
Eric

Answer (score -1):

You could also just use a `\newcommand` similar to Eric's solution.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% The table design.
\newcommand{\defaultTable}[2]{
    \begin{table}[h]
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cc}
        Column A & Column B \\
        #2
        \end{tabularx}
        \caption{#1}
    \end{table}
}
\newcommand{\defaultTableRow}[2]{#1 & #2 \\}

\begin{document}

% The creation of a table.
\defaultTable{Example}{
  \defaultTableRow{bla}{0815}
  \defaultTableRow{blup}{0815}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will avoid both your problems (the missing `\end{table}` and the error when referencing arguments in the environments closing code) without much hassle.

In fact I also like the idea of separating the table design from the table data. Especially if you create multiple tables that need to look equal.